# How and where to add join query in magento 2 for UI components

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I have referred this link

[Reference link](https://magedirect.co/resources/article/magento-2-how-to-create-admin-grid/)

Now where I have to place a code for join query multiple table for custom admin grid in magento 2

I have referred many links but got failed for ex.

adding below code in

```
Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Credits\collection.php

    protected function _initSelect()
        {
            echo 'hererer';
            die;
            parent::_initSelect();

            $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('customer_grid_flat')],
                    'main_table.customer_id = secondTable.entity_id',
                    array('*')
                );
            $this->addFilterToMap('firstname', 'secondTable.name');
            //$this->addFilterToMap('columnname2_clias', 'secondTable.columnname2');
            return $this;
        }


    <columns name="credit_listing_columns">
            <column name="customer_id">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Customer ID</label>
                    <sorting>asc</sorting>
                </settings>
            </column>
            <column name="firstname">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Customer Name</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
            <column name="credit">
...
```

what is the proper magento procedure or what is wrong with this, also I tried to `echo die;` inside this function but got failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the join query in ui component data source. 
Code in module's `di.xml`

```
----
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="anshu_custom_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveSessions\Grid\Collection</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
        <virtualType name="Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveSessions\Grid\Collection">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">anshu_custom_table</argument>
                <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveSessions</argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
----
```

Code in **app/code/Anshu/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/ActiveSessions/Grid/Collection.php**

```
----
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(-----);

        return $this;
    }
----
```

Code in ui component xml file

```
-----
<dataProvider class="Anshu\Custom\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="anshu_custom_listing_data_source">
----
```

`Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveSessions\Grid\Collection` is my ui component grid data source provider.

Comment: thanks for your answer, anshu_custom_listing_data_source' this name is sequencial or any name we can give ?

Comment: Name can be any string(it tried to have meaningful names, defining the purpose), but it should match the data source provider name in your ui component xml file.

Comment: one last query, can we use order by clause inside _initSelect() ?

Comment: Yes, we can use. I don't remember if I faced any issues with order by. Give it a try and share if it that works or if there is any issue.

Comment: Yes, its working, using `$this->setOrder('id','DESC');` :) thank you